# How to check Mesos Master?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I'm new to Mesos. I would like to know how do I know whether Mesos master is set up correctly in the node?

I have follow the set up given by http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/

I am unable to run the following command:

Comment: Start mesos master (Ensure work directory exists and has proper permissions).

> $ ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos

but it shown error given:

> ./bin/mesos-master.sh: line 24: /home/user/mesos-0.20.0/build/src/mesos-master: No such file or directory

What ways should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

First, a few questions to help us debug your build:

- Did the mesos build (`make`) complete successfully, and did `make check` pass all the tests?
- If `/home/user/mesos-0.20.0/build/src/mesos-master` does exist, do you have execute permissions on it?
- Are you running `./bin/mesos-master.sh` from within `/home/user/mesos-0.20.0/build/`, or did you move the directory elsewhere?

If this is your first attempt at Mesos and you just want to run it and try it out (rather than fix bugs and develop features for it). I would recommend using a pre-built or cloud-deployed version of Mesos, rather than trying to build it yourself. See:

- http://mesosphere.com/downloads/
- http://mesosphere.com/downloads/details/index.html#apache-mesos

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have execute (make) and (make check). But I'm not too sure whether does it pass the tests as I saw some part where it state `1697: Socket [127.0.0.1:47772] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): sever refused to accept the client` . 

For `/home/user/mesos-0.20.0/build/src/mesos-master` is a directory or ? Because it shown error state it Not a directory. I did not move to any places.

Comment: Some ZK connection errors are expected during `make check`, since we're testing in part how Mesos handles ZK failures. See the end of the `make check` output to see how many tests passed/failed.

Comment: `/home/user/mesos-0.20.0/build/src/mesos-master` should be another bash script (not a directory), so you can try viewing its contents.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to follow [Mesos Getting Started documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/getting-started/).

After your system requirements are satisfied, following the section:

> System Requirements

Once you reach the following section:

> Building Mesos

when you execute the `make` without disabling verbosity, ensure that all process completed successfully. If it stops (e.g. tipically for proxy related issues) try to fix it accordingly or otherwise post your stack somewhere and I would be happy to help (if I can).

Unfortunately, running `make check` could not reveal the problem sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the `make check` command ? It is said in the documentation that the binaries will only be available after running the `make check`command.Ì faced the same issue and it was because i didn't run that command.